# How do I deserialize a JSON array without needing a wrapper type?

Tags: json, rust, deserialization, serde

I want to deserialize the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "name": "one",
    "path": "/path/to/one"
  },
  {
    "name": "two",
    "path": "/path/to/two"
  },
  {
    "name": "three",
    "path": "/path/to/three"
  }
]
```

Into a `Vec<Worskpace>`. `Workspace` is defined below:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Workspace {
    name: String,
    path: String,
}
```

Is there a way to do that without having to do something like:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Workspacesss {
    values: Vec<Workspace>,
}
```

Comment: What part of your proposed solution do you not like? How would you use your `Workspacesss`?

Comment: @Shepmaster You're right. I thought that getting a `Vec<Workspace>` was tricky because what is deserializable (done by me) is `Workspace`. Turns out serde_json already got Vec's covered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just deserialize the vector directly:

```
let workspaces = serde_json::from_str::<Vec<Workspace>>(input);
```

Comment: I'm a fool for not understanding the serde API.